# User getting error when opening SharePoint customized Power Apps form

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, error, powerapp, list-form

I have an intake form in PowerApps (SharePoint list form) that is live, and has many users.  There are some who are receiving this error when they open the form from SharePoint:

[image]

I'm not sure why this happens only for certain users.  This particular individual has permissions to the SharePoint list:

[image]

Any help figuring this out would be great.  It's a live system, and some people can't access the form without error.

Thank you.

Comment: Are those guest/external users?

Comment: Ganesh - Yes they are.  In several of my fields , I have certain properties (Visible, DisplayMode) that change based on these: "Office365Users.MyProfileV2().mail = " and 
"Office365Users.MyProfileV2().displayName".  Using the User() function isn't consistent.

Comment: Check my answer given below for `MyProfileV2()` workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Office 365 Users connector methods/actions are limited for the guest accounts in the M365 tenant.

> [Get my profile (V2)](https://learn.microsoft.com/connectors/office365users?wt.mc_id=MVP_315224#get-my-profile-(v2)) action may fail with `401 Unauthorized` error when used by guest users. To workaround this, try specifying `Select fields parameter` explicitly to: `id, displayName, givenName, surname, mail, mailNickname, accountEnabled, userPrincipalName, department, jobTitle, mobilePhone, businessPhones, city, companyName, country, officeLocation, postalCode`.

**Documentation**: [Office 365 Users connector - Known Issues and Limitations](https://learn.microsoft.com/connectors/office365users?wt.mc_id=MVP_315224#known-issues-and-limitations)

**Example**:

```
Set(myUserProfile,Office365Users.MyProfileV2({'$select':"userPrincipalName,displayName,mail"}))
```

---

Also, `SearchUser()` and `SearchUserV2()` methods do not work for guest accounts.

Office 365 Users connector uses Microsoft Graph under the hood which has some limitations with guest users.

Check: [Can guests use Microsoft Graph with Power Apps?](https://learn.microsoft.com/power-apps/maker/canvas-apps/share-app-guests?wt.mc_id=MVP_315224#can-guests-use-microsoft-graph-with-power-apps)